# How to constrain a Union so that input and output types match?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a testcase.py:

```
import pathlib
import typing as tp


# Not under my control

PathType = tp.Union[str, pathlib.Path]
def foreign(filename: PathType) -> PathType:
    return filename


# Under my control

T = tp.TypeVar('T', str, pathlib.Path)

def my_func(filename: T) -> T:
    return foreign(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path1: str = '/abc/efg/string.py'
    san_path1: str = my_func(path1)
    print(san_path1, type(san_path1))

    path2: pathlib.Path = pathlib.Path('/abc/efg/pathlib.py')
    san_path2: pathlib.Path = my_func(path2)
    print(san_path2, type(san_path2))
```

There are two sections in this file.
In section "Not under my control" I am simulating function from module that is not under my control, but this function is defined as presented here.

In section "Under my control" I am trying to enforce that if I call my_func with str, to get back str, or if I call my_func with pathlib.Path to get back pathlib.Path, but to prevent situations in which I will call the function with str and get back pythlib.Path and vice verse.

The code works well. If I run it the output is:

```
$ python testcase.py 
/abc/efg/string.py <class 'str'>
/abc/efg/pathlib.py <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>
```

But mypy complains:

```
$ mypy testcase.py 
testcase.py:17: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[str, Path]", expected "str")
testcase.py:17: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[str, Path]", expected "Path")
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Line 17 is `return foreign(filename)`.
How to satisfy mypy?

Comment: can you guarantee `foreign` will definitely return `str` for `str` and `Path` for `Path`? Is this documented as part of the API, or is it just the current behaviour? Can you be sure they won't change the implementation without telling you? They may be using `Union` because they don't want to constrain themselves and intend to change functionality later

Comment: downvoted for terrible title

Comment: I cannot garantee anything about foreign, but I want to ensure my_func will work as I explained. If they change foreign function, my test will fail and this is OK.
Please suggest better title.

Comment: If you can't guarantee anything about the foreign function's implementation, the mypy error is correct and you can't make the guarantees about `my_func` that you want to (unless you throw exceptions for invalid types)

Comment: happy to suggest a title but first I need to understand your problem

Comment: The problem is, no matter how foreign is defined, I would like my_func to accept/return str or accept/return pathlib.Path.

Comment: say the authors of `foreign` change the implementation so that it turns a `str` into a `Path`, how would you return a `str`?

Comment: In that case my test will not pass, and I will then deal with it.

Comment: I've updated the title. Feel free to change it if it's not right

Comment: Title is much better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`foreign` doesn't guarantee that it will return a `str` for `str` input and the same for `Path`. It only guarantees what's in the types (unless documentation specifies otherwise): that it will return either type regardless of input. Since it's outside your control the authors could change the implementation such that e.g. it always returns a `Path`, thus breaking your code.

If you can't be sure how `foreign` works, you could convert as necessary

```
def my_func(filename: T) -> T:
    res = foreign(filename)
    
    return str(res) if isinstance(filename, str) else pathlib.Path(res)
```

Or, if you have tests that check `foreign` returns the same type it's given, you can just assert the types in `my_func`

```
def my_func(filename: T) -> T:
    res = foreign(filename)

    if isinstance(filename, str):
        assert instance(res, str)
        return res
    else:
        assert instance(res, pathlib.Path)
        return res
```

or even better exit on failure

```
def my_func(filename: T) -> T:
    res = foreign(filename)

    if isinstance(filename, str) and isinstance(res, str):
        return res
    elif isinstance(filename, pathlib.Path) and isinstance(res, pathlib.Path):
        return res
        
    sys.exit("Fatal error")  # we exit if our code's broken
```

or, if you don't want the runtime cost of these checks and you're happy to rely on runtime tests for verification for `foreign`, just `# type: ignore` the `return` statement in `my_func`.

Comment: I have a (py)test for that. 
I don't bother what foreign does. 
I just want to ensure from my side and my usage of my_func that whenever I call it with str to get str back and if I call it with Path to get Path back, and I would like that ensurance to be checked by mypy as part of my test suite.

Comment: @user3225309 I've added an option for if you have tests. Do mention these things in your questions. It makes it easier for people answering

Comment: I don't understand what means: "I've added an option for if you have tests".

Comment: @user3225309 the last two code snippets are for if you're confident (e.g. by pytest tests) that `foreign` returns the same type it's given